# drf: custom field validation function not being called

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a following serializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(many=True)
    image = Base64ImageField(required=False)

    def validate_image(self, value):
        import ipdb
        ipdb.set_trace()
        # if value.get('fileArray', None):
        #     if value.get('dataURL', None):
        #         return value.get('dataURL')
        #     else:
        #         raise serializers.ValidationError("No file data present")
        # else:
        #     return None

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'detail', 'image', 'true_false_answer', 'type', 'choices')
```

Then in view:

```
serializer = QuestionSerializer(data=data)
serializer.is_valid()
```

This gives me **False**
and:

```
serializer.errors
```

gives:

```
{'image': ['The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.']}
```

What I found is *validate_image* is never called.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I found is validate_image is never called. What might be the problem?

`validate_image` will be called *if* the default DRF validation passes.

It doesn't make sense to validate the image field when the serializer already knows the field isn't valid.

Comment: Is there a way to override the default DRF validation and use only our custom validation method?

Comment: @lordvcs i know it might be a bit late, but possibly by adding `required=False` to the `ChoiceSerializer` as well, in the case one would like to send back a bulk number of specially worded errors for multiple serializers. Also, it might be possible by using `Serializer` instead of `ModelSerializer` as the parent class.